# Solve the equations $z^2 + (2 - 2i)z + 2i = 0 $ by completing the square

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, complex-numbers, factoring

I tried solving this thing by completing the square and I always end up with something like this $(z^2 + (2 - 2i)z - 2i) + 2i + 2i = 0 $ and it doesn't seem like to me that you can factor the part in brackets into a square, any help is appreciated

Solve the equations $z^2 + (2 - 2i)z + 2i = 0 $ by completing the square

Comment: Sure, it is $(x-(1-i))^2$.

Comment: Hope this helps: $z^2+2z+1+2i(1-z)=1\implies (z+1)^2=2i(z-1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(1-i)^2=-2i$, so
$$z^2-(2-2i)z-2i=(z-(1-i))^2.$$

Comment: thank you but I am still a little confused on how u went from $z^2 + (2 - 2i)z + 2i = $ to $(z-(1-i))^2$

Comment: I went from your $z^2-(2-2i)z-2i$ to $(z-(1-i))^2$. It is as I explained because $(1-i)^2=-2i$. Then your equation becomes $(z-(1-i))^2=-4i$, and you still have to deal with that, by finding the square roots of $-4i$. But you did not ask about that part, only about completing the square.

Comment: okay thank you i get it now

Comment: At first sight it seems "surprising" that $-2i$ is the square of something nice!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like
$$
z^2 + (2 - 2i) z + 2i = (z + a + bi)^2 + [\text{some number}]
$$
The important thing is getting the $z$ term to match up.  In particular, since $(z + a + bi)^2 = z^2 + (2a + 2bi) z + (a + bi)^2$, you want
$$
2a + 2bi = 2 - 2i
$$
So $a = 1$ and $b = -1$.  That means $a + bi = 1 -i$, so
$$
z^2 + (2 - 2i)z + 2i = (z + 1 - i)^2 + \cdots
$$
Can you take it from there?